# Intersection of three equations, parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem says: Find the real number m, so that the intersection of the lines

$ mx+2y-1=0$ and $2x+my+3=0$ belong to $x-y-3=0$.
I am not learning math in english, I hope my translation is good enough, and where it says "it belongs" I think it means that it intersects the same point.

I tried forming a system of equation with those three and find x,y,m used the substitution method, Gaussian elimination didn't get anything, maybe there is a formula, I don't know. I would really love to have an explanation how to find the parameter.

Comment: @MyGlasses i haven't let anything out, that is everything that the problem said. I will try to substitute y=x-3 and see if i can get something out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

from the equation of the third line we have $y=x-3$. Substitute in the other two equation than solve one of them for $m$, substitute in the other equation and find $x$. Now back-substitute to find $m$ and $y$.